# What are these parallel lines on my exit stamp?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, passport-stamps, denial-of-entry

Can anyone please tell me what these two parallel lines on my exit stamp mean?

[image]

And will it impact my further application & travel to the Schengen area? It happened when I was denied entry to Croatia due to single entry Schengen visa and therefore I have no valid visa to enter Croatia. The Croatian border guard didn't stamp anything on my passport nor gave me any letter, she just kindly told us we can apply for a visa in Ljubljana. The Slovenian guard just drew two parallel lines on our exit stamp and when we left the Schengen area via Switzerland the country which issued my visa the guard just stamped me out without a single question.

Comment: Duplicate of [What are these stamps in my passport after I was advised to divert via the UK but didn't have a visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125721/what-are-these-stamps-in-my-passport-after-i-was-advised-to-divert-via-the-uk-bu)

Comment: Yes when actually did you got this and doed it effect your further travels to the schengen area.

Comment: Oh i just read your issue does it impact your further travels

Comment: There would be no impact on future travel. It's treated as if you never left the Schengen region at that time.  In effect, they voided your exit, and thus your exit stamp.

Comment: @Doc thx a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The diagonal lines mean **your exit from Schengen was cancelled**, which is indeed exactly what happened.  The stamp itself has no impact on future travel to Schengen or other countries.

However, you *have* now technically been refused entry to Croatia. Since your passport was not stamped with a refusal, this was likely processed as the Croatian equivalent of "withdrawing application to enter", but you may wish to err on the side of caution and state "yes" if you're asked in the future whether you have ever been refused entry.

Comment: Thx for your answer so my caution is just to declare my problems in the past.However iam concerned it  bring me bigger issues  the next time i travel despite for say valid visa, booking and showing returnt tickets af far as you know and you have heard , because i am really scared to travel since this tragedy happened to me?