# Why do I have two stamps, one with two diagonal lines, on departure from Germany?

Tags: schengen, transit, europe

I was in Germany at work for 3 months as a student. When I returned to my country at the airport, they stamped me and put this on the stamp and put a new normal stamp underneath, they didn't tell me anything from there and I returned to my country. Do you know what this means?
[image: passport stamps]

To be more specific, why there are two stamps and what is the meaning of the first one(that blue stamp and blue text)?

Comment: Are you asking why there are two stamps?

Comment: When was the blue text added?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In this case, it is probably due to the smudges making the stamp illegible

Comment: Upper page, you are shown to have left, this was cancelled, the cancellation was confirmed with the blue stamp and dark blue signature, lower page, you are again shown to have left. As xngtng commented, the second "you left" is more readable than the first one. Net result, one departure.

Comment: Or even [Two parallel diagonal lines on a Schengen passport stamp](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178858/47309) or [Two diagonal lines in passport stamp](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/182273/47309) or [What's the meaning of these two diagonal lines through my passport stamp?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/182873/47309)

Answer (score 5):

Upper page, you are shown to have left, but this was cancelled with the slashes. The cancellation was confirmed with the blue stamp and dark blue signature (a rather common Bavarian name). So according to the upper page, you have not left.

Lower page, you are again shown to have left. As xngtng commented, the second "you left" is more readable than the first one, which is the presumable reason.

Net result, one valid departure stamp, one invalidated stamp saying nothing, you left once and not twice.