# What's the meaning of these two diagonal lines through my passport stamp?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, passport-stamps

I would like to know what these lines in my passport mean. Any ideas? Would this affect me when I plan to return to Europe?

[image: overlapping "Athina" plane stamp and "LFT Paris Nord" train stamp, with two diagonal lines through the lower left/upper left]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are these stamps in my passport after I was advised to divert via the UK but didn't have a visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125721/what-are-these-stamps-in-my-passport-after-i-was-advised-to-divert-via-the-uk-bu)

Comment: What is your citizenship and if you needed a visa, what are the terms of that visa? When did you enter the Schengen Area before that aborted exit on March 4th? Are there any other entry or exit stamps with dates between the two stamps on your picture? If so, what are their dates?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you meant to take a train Paris-London but didn't catch it for whatever reason, thus the French cancelled your exit. It won't be an issue for future applications.

Comment: in fact, i got this stamp in Athens,when i left. the immigration officer told me you stayed 2 months in Paris,don’t come back! and then i noticed those lines in my passport. im worried it would be a problem for my future travels within europe,important to say that i didn’t overstay as im allowed to be 90 days in Schengen and i stayed less than that

Comment: @karen The lines are on the lower stamp, not the upper one. The Athens stamp is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

The double diagonal lines in the upper left corner of an entry or exit stamp mean they that specific stamp has been cancelled.

Here the lines are in the stamp related to your departure from Paris to London via the Eurostar on March 4th.

You probably went through exit passport control, there was an issue (like being refused entry into the UK at the UK passport control just after the French one), and you were re-admitted into France, so they cancelled the exit stamp.

Depending on when you entered the Schengen Area and if there are any other entry and exit stamps between the cancelled French stamp and the valid Greek stamp, there could be an issue or not.

If there are no other stamps in between and you entered the Schengen Area before February 28th, then you did overstay, and you will have issues entering the Schengen Area again or getting a visa.

If there are no other stamps and you entered on February 28th or later then it depends on whether you needed a visa or not, and if so, what the terms of the visa were (duration and validity). If you didn’t need a visa all is fine, but you you are close to the 90/180 limit, so most likely you can’t come back before 3 months.

If you needed a visa it depends on whether you respected the terms of your visa.

If there are other stamps in between then it’s more complicated but we lack information.

Comment: thank you so much!! i really appreciate your comment,and yes as you mentioned,i was refused my entry to Uk ,so i stayed in france for 2 months and then left via Athens,before 90 days,i didn’t overstay.

Comment: @karen then, provided you are from a visa-free country, or the terms of your visa allowed for that duration, you are fine, but can’t come back to the Schengen Area for nearly 90 days to meet the 90/180 limit.